# QApplication not executed in Sublime Text 2 (python)

Tags: python, pyqt4, sublimetext2

I've recently made the IDE switch to Sublime Text 2.
It works in all ways except when trying to run code for PyQt4 GUIs.

As well as not performing any Qt library auto-completion, calling QApplication.exec_() does not launch the application. No windows spawn and no output is made; no error messages, just nothing.

The OP in this page http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/93277-pyqt-applications-doesnt-show-up-after-build-ctrlb/ claims that adding `"shell":"true"` to the `python.sublime-build` dictionary in the `python.sublime-package` file solves the problem, but so far, it hasn't.

According to Sublime documentation (based off another value), the actual addition should probably be `"shell:true`, but that also has no effect.

I'm finding it extremely difficult to find the relevant information online; I can't even begin to fathom the cause of the problem.
Any assistance is extremely appreciated!

Specs:
Windows 7 (64 bit)
Python 2.7.1
Sublime Text 2 (32 bit)
PyQt4.7

Comment: I have `"shell":"true"` in the `Python.sublime-build` _file_, which is in `Data/Packages/Python`. This is in the installation folder. But mine is portable version. I'm not sure where this would be in the normal installation (maybe in `AppData`?).

Comment: In the installed version, the equivalent is the `python.sublime-package` file in `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\Pristine Packages` as aforementioned. This does not resolve the issue.

Comment: No, not the one in `Program Files`. Check under one of the folders in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData` for a `Sublime Text 2` folder.

Comment: Adding `"shell":"true"` to `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Python\Python.sublime-build` solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Other possible solution is:

Go to Preferences→Browse Packages, open the Default directory and then open exec.py in the editor. Around line 26, you’ll see:

```python
# Hide the console window on Windows
startupinfo = None
if os.name == "nt":
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
```

Comment out the last line of this block. Now, whenever you start a Python program, the console will be displayed.